# Vue.Js teting with jest error axios

Tags: javascript, testing, vue.js, axios, jestjs

I'm writing test for components which uses axios.
I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

after
 `yarn test`.
I tried to import axios to my *spec.js files, but it doesn't work.
What should i do to pass that tests?

Comment: `import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '../src/components/courses/Courses'

describe('Component', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component)
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})`

Comment: Please update *your question* with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `axios` in your `*spec.js` files:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    get: () => {},
}));

describe('Test.spec.js', () => {
    ...
});
```